# GAS: copy one data validation (dropdown) in N number of rows and set unique value in each dropdown

Tags: validation, google-apps-script

**Edited for clarity and to add images**

Using Google Apps Script, how can I:

1. copy a range from Section 2 sheet (G11:H11, with a checkbox & dropdown) into range G12:G25 N number of times (based on the number of non-empty rows in MASTER DROPDOWN sheet under same header title as 'Section 2'!A2) and then,
2. set a different value in each dropdown (each unique value listed in MASTER DROPDOWN sheet under the correct header).

For example, first image is "MASTER DROPDOWN" sheet.

[image]

This second image is "Section 2" sheet. The user can add or delete items on the list using the buttons on the right side of the page.

[image]

And this last image is "Section 2" sheet. I cannot understand how to write the code for this... When user presses "Reset list" button, I want to copy checkbox and dropdown menu (from G11:H11) N number of times (N=3 based on number of items from MASTER DROPDOWN under Section 2). In each dropdown, I want to set value with each item from the original list in the MASTER DROPDOWN sheet. This process should be dynamic and work on Section 1 and Section 3 sheet (not in worksheet currently).

[image]

Any advice on the script verbage to search/learn about this type of functionality, or some direction on the script for this is much appreciated. Here's a link to my code that I have so far...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdlJdhA0ZJOIwLA9dw5-y5v1FyLfRSywjmQ543EwMFQ/edit?usp=sharing

```
function newListAlert (){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert("Are you sure you want to delete your current list and create a new one?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
 
  if(response == ui.Button.YES) {
    newList();
  } else {
  }
}

function newList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("G11:H25");
  var options = {contentsOnly: true, validationsOnly: true};
 
  //clear current list
  range.clear(options);

  //add new item to list in first row of range
  addNewItem();

  //copy new datavalidation row above based on number of non-empty rows in MASTER DROPDOWN with same header as active sheet (-1)
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MASTER DROPDOWN");
  var range = ss.getRange("A2");
    
    if (range.getCell(1,1)){

    var section = datass.getRange(1,1,1,datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var sectionIndex = section[0].indexOf(range.getValue()) + 1;

    var validationRange = datass.getRange(4,sectionIndex,19);//19 columns: checklist has a maximum of 18 rows (+ 1 for "select option")
    }

    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the flow 1 to 5 in your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: @Tanaike, I tried to simplify my question and I added 3 images. The first image is the "MASTER DROPDOWN" sheet; the second image is "Section 2" sheet with only 1 value ("Market Research") in a list, and third image is "Section 2" sheet with each unique value listed in multiple dropdowns (values are from D5:D7 on "MASTER DROPDOWN").

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, where can I see the input and output situations you expect?

Comment: My goal is to write a script to make the third image- And to make it dynamic code because I will copy "Section 2" sheet and make many sheets (e.g. "Section 3" sheet, Section 4" sheet, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, when the reset button is clicked, you want to achieve the situation of 3rd image. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The input values for the data validation (dropdown) are on the "MASTER DROPDOWN" sheet. These values are in the dropdown menu in "Section 2" sheet. Am I understanding your question correctly? I apologize if I misunderstood your question. Here is the link to the sheet if it is helpful. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdlJdhA0ZJOIwLA9dw5-y5v1FyLfRSywjmQ543EwMFQ/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: @Tanaike, yes, my goal is to achieve the 3rd image.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `My goal is to write a script to make the third image- And to make it dynamic code because I will copy "Section 2" sheet and make many sheets (e.g. "Section 3" sheet, Section 4" sheet, etc.).`?

Comment: Yes, please ask any questions. I apologize for the confusion. This is a difficult function to describe.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `My goal is to write a script to make the third image`, I understood that you want to achieve the 3rd image when the reset button is clicked. But I cannot understand the relationship between `My goal is to write a script to make the third image` and `And to make it dynamic code because I will copy "Section 2" sheet and make many sheets (e.g. "Section 3" sheet, Section 4" sheet, etc.).`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Basically, I want to find the header listed in 'Section 2'!A2 and then find it on 'MASTER DROPDOWN'!A1:AD. Then I want to copy all non-empty values under that header from 'MASTER DROPDOWN' into 'Section 2' sheet, range H11:H25. But all the values should be in a dropdown, rather than a simple text list. They should also have a checkbox in G11:G25 next to dropdowns.

Comment: Maybe "Dynamic" is the wrong word. I will copy this sheet many times, for example... to make a "section 3" sheet, "section 4" sheet, etc. So, I want to use this function for many sheets, not just section 2 header on "Section 2" sheet. Does that help?

Comment: 本当にごめんなさい. I don't think I explained this very well. I'll keep searching for more answers so that I can ask better questions. 頑張ります!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about modifying `newList()` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function newList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
  sheet.getRange("G11:H25").clear({ contentsOnly: true, validationsOnly: true });
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER DROPDOWN");
  var values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var obj = values[0].map((_, c) => values.map(r => r[c])).reduce((o, [h, , , ...v], i) => {
    if (h != "") {
      v = v.filter(String);
      v.shift();
      o[h] = { values: v, range: srcSheet.getRange(4, i + 1, v.length + 1) };
    }
    return o;
  }, {});
  if (obj[sheetName]) {
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
      .setAllowInvalid(false)
      .setHelpText('Select an option from the menu. To add more options to the dropdown list, go to MASTER DROPDOWN tab.')
      .requireValueInRange(obj[sheetName].range, true)
      .build();
    var d = obj[sheetName].values.map(_ => [validationRule]);
    var v = obj[sheetName].values.map(e => [e]);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 8, obj[sheetName].values.length).setDataValidations(d).setValues(v).offset(0, -1).insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the values for DataValidations are retrieved from the sheet "MASTER DROPDOWN", and using the sheet name, the dataValidation rules are created, and put to the column "H". And also, the checkboxes are put to the column "G" of the same rows of the dataValidations.
- In this case, for example, when you add a new sheet of "Section 1" and run `newList()`, the dropdown list including "Engineering" and "Design" is put to the column "H" and the checkboxes are also put to the column "G".

#### Note:

- In this modification, the sheet name like "Section 2" is used for searching the column of "MASTER DROPDOWN" sheet. So please be careful about this.
- And, from your current script, the last row is used for putting to the dropdown list and checkboxes. So when you want to modify this, please modify the above script.
- This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. So when your actual Spreadsheet is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [setDataValidations(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)
- [insertCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcheckboxes)

Comment: I input your code and it works great. Thank you! I did make one change. Instead of matching the sheet name, I decided to match the header name. So, I changed `var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();` to `var headername = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,1).getValues();` , which works very well also. It is good to understand both of these options!

Comment: I do have one more question. For example, if I add a new item to the data validation list on MASTER DROPDOWN sheet (e.g. original range is D4:D7 and now it is D4:D8), is it possible to see this new item in the dropdown menus in Section 2 sheet), without pressing newList button again? I only want to see the new item in the dropdown menus that already exist. I hope this makes sense. Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: The maximum range for all lists in MASTER DROPDOWN is A4:AD22 (maximum number of rows = 19 per list).

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BegintoCode Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.